# Setting up a Wamp Server

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, localhost

I'm new to web development, and I need help setting up CSS and javascript files.
Right now, I can only view the HTML file.

So, I've added all the files to the www folder, and changed the reference in the html to account for that. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

This is the HTML file.
When I run it locally, the CSS works, but not the Javascript. From my limited understanding, you can't run Javascript from local files for security reasons.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:\\C:\wamp\www\dojo\goodlooks.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:\\C:\wamp\www\dojoMovement.js"></script>

        <title>Dojo</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Dojo</h1>

        <div id="left" class="picture">

            <img class="photo" src="http://www.antiquity.tv/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/dali-art-salvador-dali.jpg"/>
            <p class="artistName"> Dali</p>


            <div class="bio">
            <img class="personPic" src="http://blog.nj.com/jets_impact/2009/08/large_marked826.jpg"/>
            <p>Plays football in his spare time.</p>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="versus">VS</div>




        <div id="right" class="picture">
            <img class="photo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Claude_Monet,_Saint-Georges_majeur_au_cr%C3%A9puscule.jpg"/>
            <p class="artistName">Monet</p>


            <div class="bio">
                <img class="personPic" src="http://img4.allvoices.com/thumbs/image/609/480/95681263-maria-sharapova.jpg" />
                <p>Plays tennis in her spare time.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
h1 {
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;

}

body{
    background-color:orange;
}






.picture, .versus {

    display:inline;

}

#left{
    background-color:blue;
}



#right{
    background-color:red;
}

.versus{
    margin:50px;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:yellow;


}

.picture{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:40px;
    margin:100x;
}

.photo{
    height:200px;
    width: 450px;   

}

.bio{
    display:inline-block;
    float:bottom;
    }

.personPic{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    }
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".versus").slideDown('slow');
});
```

//Not much, just trying to make it work.

Comment: This question is not suited for Stackoverflow, the scope is too broad. We can answer only specific coding questions.

Comment: http://www.wampserver.com | http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html | Do you even google?

Comment: Without actually seeing what's wrong, we can't possibly know what you're missing.  "I added files but it doesn't work" isn't a problem description.  What is the folder structure which contains the files?  What is the HTML code which references a file?  What is the server's response when making the request for the file?

Comment: Haven't seen anything yet, the stuff on there hasn't really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I've added all the files to the www folder, and changed the reference in the html to account for that. What am I missing here?

If you had done that, then you would have something like `href="http://localhost` (or a relative URI) and not  `href="file:\\C:\wamp`

You need to change the URLs to point to the HTTP server you are running, and not the location it tries to read files form on the file system.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like what I'm looking for. But, how do I get at the specific file from there. href="http://localhost/www/dojo/goodlooks.css" ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Or I suppose it'd be: href="localhost/dojo/goodlooks.css"? Unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: @redRaven: You forgot the "http://" at the start of the reference.  Otherwise it's going to look for the file in a *folder* called "localhost" which doesn't exist.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Thank you both for your help. However, my js file still doesn't work  <script type="text/javascript" href="http://localhost/dojo/Movement.js"></script>

Comment: Do you get the right file if you visit `http://localhost/dogo/Movement.js`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I don't

Comment: Then you need to figure out where on your web server you put it.

Comment: Its all in the same www folder

Comment: If it is in the www folder, why are you saying it is in the dogo folder?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that you put it in a *dojo* folder but you mistyped the `j` as a `g`?

Comment: I put it in src="http://localhost/dojo/Movement.js

Comment: Not sure where you see it spelled "dogo" but I put it in the dojo folder, which is inside the www folder. Thanks again for your help